# How to caculate the standard deviation be for the vatiable in the matrix craeted

Tags: tensorflow, variables, matrix

I used tensorflow 1.4 and I want to test the tool.
like an example below:

import tensorflow as tf

input=[50,10]

```
O1 = layers.fully connected(input, 20, tf.sigmoid)
```

I guess the code is okay but Not so sure how to figure out the standard deviation be for the vatiable in the matrix craeted? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using Latest Tensorflow version 2.5, you can calculate standard deviation using

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
tf.math.reduce_std(x)
```

Output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.118034>
```